# Sum variable in awk 'if condition' under 'for loop'

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file with 3 columns (n=3) and FS = " " (file1.txt):

```
cat file1.txt
3.1 6.6 0
2.4 7.1 4.9
5.7 1.2 6.1
```

Here, I would like to give an 'if condition' in `awk` for each column, where it would test for a condition and return a value of 1 or 0 (depending on the result) and store it in another variable, such as:

```
#!/bin/bash

#code1
awk '{

if  ($1 != 0)

    { x1 = 1 }
    else
    { x1 = 0}


if  ($2 != 0)

    { x2 = 1 }
    else
    { x2 = 0}


if  ($3 != 0)

    { x3 = 1 }
    else
    { x3 = 0}

     x = x1 + x2 + x3
     print x;

     }' file1.txt > output.txt
```

The desired output in this case would be:

```
cat output.txt
2
3
3
```

Which I am getting without any problem.

Consider the case in which instead of having 3 columns, there were say 10 columns (n=10) and the same `if` condition is to be applied to each column. In this case I would like to run a `for` loop, under which the same `if` condition is to be defined. But I think I am making an error in specifying the nth field. Also how to perform the sum of the xn variables (x1 + X2 + X3...X10). Here is what I have tried so far:

```
   awk '{
   for (n=1; n<=10; n++)

    if ($n != 0)

    { xn = 1 }

    else

    { xn = 0 }

    xn+=xn 
    print xn;

             }' file1_10fields.txt > output_10fields.txt
```

This is not giving me the correct output. Where am I making the mistake? Is there a more elegant way to do this?
Are `xn+=xn` and `print xn` supposed to be outside the loop? Also, what is the correct way to get the sum?

Comment: It is not clear what output you want from this awk. Can you clarify?

Comment: Hi anubhava, as you can see from the `file1.txt` and the `output.txt`, the aim is to assign to a variable `xn` a value 1 if `$n != 0` else assign 0. So if you see in `file1.txt`, in row#1 you have 1 + 1 + 0 = 2. 
In this case we have 3 columns, but I would like to do it for n number of columns. 
Please let me know if it is still not clear, I will try to explain better. Thanks

Comment: I edited a bit, and if you now see in #code1, 3 conditions, doing same operation on 3 columns. I would like to do it for n number of columns.

Comment: Ok got it, posted an answer below.

Comment: Think positive! Always use positive rather than negative conditions in your code and it'll be easier to read and avoids the possibility of the dreaded double-negative. In this case, in your code above you should think/write `if  ($1 == 0) { x1 = 0 } else { x1 = 1}` instead of `if  ($1 != 0) { x1 = 1 } else { x1 = 0}`.

Comment: @EdMorton: Thanks for the comment. You are right, I can indeed change this condition. But again, how do I calculate x1+x2+..+xn ?

Comment: Why is `x2` always assigned 0 in the working code? Also, the shebang is spelled `#!/bin/bash`, not `!#/bin/bash`.  This suggests that you aren't showing us an exact copy of what you're executing.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler: My apologies for that error, I have edited it. I had made sevral copies of code to execute and I was copy pasting from these copies. And I am not yet very good with indentation of lines here to put it in a code notation, so I made some errors. I haven't slept in 19 hours! Thanks for pointing out the errors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this awk:

```
awk '{sum=0; for (i=1; i<=NF; i++){sum += $i ? 1 : 0} print sum}' file
2
3
3
```

- [Read more about ternary operator](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/02/awk-conditional-statements/)

> Awk has conditional operator i.e **ternary operator** ( ?: ) whose feature is similar to the awk If Else Statement. If the conditional-expression is true, action1 will be performed and if the conditional-expression is false action2 will be performed.

Comment: Thanks, I did not know about the ternary operator! Here is my follow-up question : Where in this awk code does it check for the condition `$n != 0` ? I would like to know because if next time I want to check instaed of `$n != 0` say `$n != 100`. Thanks again!

Comment: The test `$i` is shorthand for (and could be replaced with) `($i!=0)`

Comment: @rohit: Sorry to respond late. Yes as Floris commented `$i ?` is same as `$i!=0 ?` here.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you're expecting to see:

```
$ awk '
{
    sum = 0
    for (i=1; i<=NF; i++) {
        sum += ($i == 0 : 0 : 1)
        # or `sum += ($i ? 1 : 0)`
        # or `sum += ($i != 0)`
    }
    print sum

}
' file
2
3
3
```

but you could alternatively do this with GNU awk for `\<`...`\>` word-boundaries:

```
$ gawk '{ print gsub(/\<[^0][^ ]*\>/,1) }' file
2
3
3
```

If you like the loop, then you should accept @anubhava's answer, but do add the parens around the ternary expression so it'll work on all awks, and it makes the code a little clearer.

Comment: Is not the first part of this this just a 100% equal solution that anubhava posted some 30 minutes ago?

Comment: Yes, except for the parentheses around the ternary operator to avoid syntax errors on some awks. I had first hit the "post" button by mistake before adding the important part at the bottom so there was a brief window of 30 secs or so when it was otherwise exactly same solution as anubhava's.

Comment: You could also use `awk '{ sum = 0; for (i = 1; i <= NF; i++) { sum += ($i != 0) } print sum; }'` (your last edit added the inverse condition as an alternative; I think that's an oops!).  Does the `gsub` version recognize `0.0` as zero? The comparison versions do.  Granted the input data has `0` and not `0.0`, but...

Comment: @JonathanLeffler you're right, I needed it to be `!=` and yeah you're right again I noticed the original gsub() I'd posted wouldn't work if there were zeros anywhere in the number so I modified it now and it'll cover the `0.0` case you mention too. Thanks.

Comment: @EdMorton: The `gsub` method seems very elegant. Thank you. I am not very familiar with `\<...\>` word-boundaries, but I will definitely take a look at how it works.